# Is it standard for #if to assume undefined symbolic constants as 0?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

In this `c` program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

        #if UnDefinedSymbolicConstant==0
                printf("UnDefinedSymbolicConstant is equal to 0\n ");
        #else
                printf("UnDefinedSymbolicConstant is not equal to 0\n");

        #endif
        return 0;
}
```

**UnDefinedSymbolicConstant** has not been `#define` anywhere, still it **is being assumed as 0** and gives the [output on `gcc-4.3.4`](http://ideone.com/dIzNx)   as:

```
UnDefinedSymbolicConstant is equal to 0
```

so, 
**Is this the standard behaviour or it works like this only in gcc?**

Comment: A good way to find out if something is standard or not is -std=c99 -pedantic. This should disable all gcc extensions. Without them, gcc conforms rather well to the standard.

Comment: Are you sure `-std=c99 -pedantic` catches all non-standard constructs? It seems to be intended to, but if I'm not mistaken, it still misses some. Basically all you can rely on `-std=c99` to do is avoid allowing things that conflict with the standards-specified behavior, but it doesn't necessarily prevent you from doing things that don't conflict with but aren't specified by the standard. `-pedantic` is intended to warn you about the latter but I'm not convinced it's complete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is specified by the standard in 6.10.1:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0

Answer (score 6):

It is the default, but you might at least generate warnings for this using the `-Wundef` option to gcc.

> **`-Wundef':**
>    Warn whenever an identifier which is not a macro is encountered in
>    an `#if' directive, outside of `defined'.  Such identifiers are
>    replaced with zero.